# Make Data Un-formatable on USB Devices

Tags: usb, formatting

Sometimes ago one of my friends, copied some pictures in my USB, then He made them hidden by a software. After that He did a trick (which I did not understand).

After that He told me those hidden pictures won't format if you format your USB. then He formatted the USB, and then He easily made pictures shown.

I mean formatting did not affect those hidden pictures.
Now I was formatting that device, it only can be formatted on fast mode, but in full mode it will stop at the end progress and I should cancel formatting.

But Also those pictures (which is hidden) won't be deleted or formatted.

I want to know How such trick can be done? How can I make some data hidden and those data won't be deleted after formatting...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to protect the data as it will never get deleted anyway.

Deleting a file or "formatting" (changing the file system type) a drive does not usually erase any file data. It removes any information about how to find any files. Just like you can "undelete" files, you can "unformat" whole drives (both operations basically restore the table, that shows where to find files, from data still on the disk).

Comment: Hi oliver, I did not understood your meaning. my friend will hide those pictures. then he will format the device (normally all files should be deleted) but after formatting without using any recovery tool he made those hidden pictures shown. How is it possible?

Comment: @Stranger I don't see how that's possible. How did he make them appear? I would assume he tried to trick you. But if not, I'd like to know how he did it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend might have used a recovery software to 'restore' the lost files' path since the files (in this case pictures) do not get deleted.  When you delete a file, it basically deletes the path and not the file itself.  Considering that the 'deleted' and 'restored' files were photos, which would have been within a couple of MB in size, it is much faster and easier to restore them using any restoring software like EaseUS Data Recovery.